# setBackgroundColor recycleView in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have trying to setBackgroundColor recycleView in fragment like in tutorial.

> ```
> override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
>                           savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
>
>     recycleViewRandom.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
>
>     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycle_view, container, false)
> }
> ```

and here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.MainFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleViewRandom"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

everything looks good, same as in tutorial, but I have got from IDE:

> setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference

How is it possible that is null ?

Comment: it's not duplicate, your link is about java, not Kolitn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [**`NullPointerException`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference that has the null value.

**Declare**

```
 lateinit var                            recycleViewRandom: RecyclerView
```

**Then**

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycle_view, container, false)
        initUI(contentView)
        return contentView
    }
```

You should Initialize **`RecyclerView`**.

```
    fun initUI(contentView: View)
    {
        recycleViewRandom= contentView.findViewById(R.id.recycleViewRandom)
        recycleViewRandom.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
     }
```

Comment: can you describe this ?

Comment: ok thank I know what is npe, but why this need "initUI" ?

Comment: @jackfield Initialize RECYCLERVIEW into `initUI` section.

Comment: @jackfield npe stands for `NullPointerException`. I have already described .

Comment: content view should be initialize with var first ?

Comment: ok, work, thanks, but contentView should be also initialize "var" ?

Comment: @jackfield you can.